# Split and create data from a column to many columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame in which the values of one of its columns looks like that

```
print(VCF['INFO'].iloc[0])
```

Results (Sorry I can copy and paste this data as I am working from a cluster without an internet connection)

[image]

I need to create new columns with the name END, SVTYPE and SVLEN and their info as values of that columns. Following the example, this would be

```
END         SVTYPE   SVLEN-
224015456    DEL     223224913
```

The rest of the info contained in the column INFOI do not need it so far.
The information contained in this column is huge but as far I can read there is not more something=value as you can see in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `.str.extract`:

```
extracted = df['INFO'].str.extract('END=(?P<END>.+?);SVTYPE=(?P<SVTYPE>.+?);SVLEN=(?P<SVLEN>.+?);')
```

Output:

```
>>> extracted
         END SVTYPE       SVLEN
0  224015456    DEL  -223224913
```